# Excel VBA - Logarthmic x-axis

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. I am trying to plot a scatterplot using Excel VBA. I have chosen the x-axis to be plotted on a log scale. The issue is with the minimum value on the x-axis. I would like to have the y-axis plotted corresponding to 0.1. But it is being plotted corresponding to 1.

I tried to make the change using this piece of code

```
With .Axes(xlCategory)
     .ScaleType = xlLogarithmic
     .MinimumScale = 0.1
```

Still the probelm persists. I am able to shift the y-axis towards right but not to left of 1.

Please help to fix this issue.

Thanks,
Regards,
Kishor

Comment: Do you mean that you want your y-axis to cross the x-axis at 0.1?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the above issue using CrossesAt. Below is the code

```
With .Axes(xlCategory)
     .ScaleType = xlLogarithmic
     .MinimumScale = 0.1
     .CrossesAt = 0.1
End With
```